# Data showing in Exponential format

Tags: c#, asp.net, number-formatting

My data **0.00007173535** is showing as **7.1735351E-05** in aspx page.

My required format is decimal even the number has 20 decimal points.
I know its a small thing but couldn't figure it out.

My code is below that is in a repeater.

`<%# Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Ranking.Rating")),12)%>`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [`"F"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString) as well.

```
yourValue.ToString("F20");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `ToString(format)` on it:

```
0.00007173535.ToString("0.0#################")
```

outputs

```
0.00007173535
```

or

```
0.00007173535.ToString("N12")
```

outputs

```
0.000071735350
```

See [MSDN: Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

---

In your case this would be:

```
Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Ranking.Rating")).ToString("N12")
```

Comment: how to call it with Eval?

Comment: `string.Format(Eval("value"),"{0:0.##################}");`

Comment: safi, its other way around :p

Comment: have done it string.Format("{0:0.0##############}", Eval("Ranking.Elo")).Substring(0,12) thanks, may be you are coding in arabic :d